# VPN That Hijacks Lan (Can I use a VM?)

Tags: networking, vpn, local-area-network

I have to use a VPN for work 'citrix anyconnect vpn' which unfortunately also routes lan through the VPN. This is a feature of the VPN.

Is there a good / easy way or guide to do something like setting a VM with the VPN software installed and running on it, and then routing all the host internet traffic through the VM but keeping the host's lan traffic on the local lan (not VPN).

Comment: Can you finish writing your question? Keeping in mind that this site is for **professional system adminitrators**.  If you aren't the sysadmin of the VPN server, this is probably the wrong place for you to be asking that question.

Comment: Apologies about the question, I needed to login to post and stack overflow must have a bug with it as it returned with an incomplete question. I am a professional sys admin.

Comment: What do you mean by "routes LAN through the VPN"?

Comment: He means all his LAN traffic goes over the VPN link once it's established, and the solution he's looking for is 'split-tunnelling'.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you proposed likely wouldn't work, due to the traffic being confined to the tunnel.  Really for the same reason that you're confined to the VPN network when you're logged in on the PC to begin with.  The solution for this is split tunneling.  If it's enabled on the VPN server you'll have an option in the VPN client to enable it.